# Why Splash response is not readable after 200 response?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a js rendering website and while I am scraping, I am getting 200 response as follow;

```
<200 https://www.sokmarket.com.tr/mevsim-sebzeleri-c-1821>
```

Here is my request with Splash;

```
def start_requests(self):
    lua_script = '''
    function main(splash)
        local url = splash.args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(5))

        return {
            html = splash:html(),
            url = splash:url(),
        }
    end
    '''
    urls = Findurl(self.name)
    for url in urls:
        request = SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
        args={"lua_source":lua_script}
        )
        yield request
```

After create request, I am printing the body like this;

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(response)
    print(response.text)
```

And here is the not readable output;

```
<html><head></head><body>�X�r����R�Z�e��$�S;�y�&amp;{��&amp;yP�� �)aL����+�c���_i�/+;U����A_N7u}�Po2��:Mn�ͧ�0���V6΁E7�)hf�K�r��.tܾ�;��R���Di��ݲV��I�&lt;R���F�װ�3v��R�
�                                                       ��!Tm?  g����br��Cu,%���]ٱ�y��Ea�Fl4��e!0�r|��^L��Km?~G퐅Kh�Rh%�2(!d�|d?!�+ȏvw�ږ)�H��:.n-   �9&gt;�����ڝ�ݙ��{���@�;�L*}�n�#����     �kΒv��OR��i���E���9λ��KH�-����C�X�`oy�x��A���2���*6�"a)�0
�o���f�������Nn�rtN�\���-��/�S��~`]�֗=+诃������S��N&amp;�#�?
�(m���g�^�8�"��Y�A����y����Z_b�v����m�^�޴h��}��eYm-�p�~A\���h0��5��E��_�s�[�Zo�{�&gt;���H
��ww�a0�M��n����I'�r�@㸻2쪳�;Lƭ?��Hh|��_��QS����{�6/����15Kt��@��O���n�'6B��u#�D|'.N����]�4&amp;�R��=�h��M<i���}�b.�qh�m��:���G��F-�����&lt;�wϰ��?�l;;#Ϫ�m1_�����+�O�&gt;o�&amp;'vJ��1�zo�f����հ�h��9���N�r]U���\y�"�7l6�¿���q!B����z�� ƨj�0�q�1��[��td_p2�="">lҹLZ�����ҩX ��Zϝ�x/A_%��eT$`�\���#���F�[����TN�[X{��M���Z�xHO�i�&lt;�ey�M�;�V��y��BU,���"I\��G��p�%�Eы.���O�v��ڤVH�3�0��P��&gt;����|#B#ʼ\��6�J&gt;�t��B��,���������:��
��+b�                                                                                            .4�M��.@�:�+�X����[�J@yi����ۄ�0i�]�4���;
D8w�T�'غ��%vek�%xO�6��M�?
 ��7G�.q�       ��R�F�ĥUh�pt�7G��I�ƾ�p��|�ƈ#�'O"r/�"�1FG�����H/y�`�a���d�HA.o�R�?�ڒzJ�hwRM�a�J�x̜#�u�&gt;fd $���S11�� y=��N�)^�L�#��u��&amp;��TY�"���(xR�S��N����E~�x,</i���}�b.�qh�m!��V����L;Z��}�w���jΥ����F�m�|�B�E�)���@U�<m��Χ���?�x_�. ��="" ��ah6g="" ��i�w�a="c�����p����Tc             z��></g��3a��,li[iyb��5��></m��Χ���?�x_�.></body></html>                                       :]�}��}����ֺ�ݱڭG9$" `q�0��i�="" f�?�v�d�i�r�x�*�="0 %��z���5��g�w.{�i�e��="">�.Gcޞ��&gt;
```

I run splash with Docker compose and all tests works. I add following lines to my settings;

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'crawler.crawler.middlewares.FirstBotSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,

}
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
```

I also test with Selenium and it crawls the page readable. But I need to crawl with Splash.

I try with proxy but the result is the same. I am new at splash. I don't get what am I missing?.

Comment: what do you get with normal Selenium? Maybe server sends text in encoding different then `utf-8` and Splash has problem to convert it. OR maybe server send with compresion and it can't uncompress it.

Comment: @furas everything works fine at selenium. I can't even see anything after encoding, when I encode it looks soo weird again.